# How to edit only the last modified annotation (Ink) using JavaScript with Acrobat XI?

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat

I need to create several buttons in a PDF which when pressed will change the color of the Ink/Pencil tool in Acrobat. I am not proficient in JavaScript and have been struggling to find adequate documentation for what I am trying to accomplish.

I have found a way to do the reverse, I can make an annotation and have the button change the color of the Ink after it has been drawn. This satisfies my needs but I have not figured out how to only edit the LAST modified/created annotation. So far I have the following:

```
var buttonColor = this.getField("button").strokeColor;
this.syncAnnotScan();
var annots = this.getAnnots()
    nSortBy: ANSB_ModDate
    bReverse: true;

for (var i = 0; i < annots.length; i++) {
    if (annots[i].type == "Ink") {
        annots[i].strokeColor = buttonColor;
    }
}
```

This results in the button changing ALL Ink annotations; I am just not sure how to tell the script to only edit the LAST created/modified annotation (if possible), everything else is working as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to sort the annots to get to the last one created, it's always the last item in the array. You don't need to pass any parameters to getAnnots().

```
var buttonColor = this.getField("button").strokeColor;
this.syncAnnotScan();
var annots = this.getAnnots();

if (annots[annots.length-1].type == "Ink") {
    annots[annots.length-1].strokeColor = buttonColor;
}
```

You can see a PDF with this working at the URL below.
https://files.acrobat.com/a/preview/69dd17f9-66f5-496b-a2d1-bfaab21ccdec

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I understand how this should work now but I haven't had any success working with your script: Upon running it the console returns 'Undefined' rather than the 'buttonColor' value (RGB,x,x,x) and nothing changes.

Comment: I've edited my answer... this time I actually tested it :)

Comment: Thank you! It is working perfectly now and I am walking away with a greater understanding of JS. I initially was just taking unrelated example scripts and editing them for my needs but now I fully understand the process. I wasn't familiar with 'event.target', this saves me a lot of work as I was using 'getField' to set the variable for each button. Your solution allows me to use the same script for every button (var buttonColor = event.target.strokeColor), thanks again!